# Проблема в обработке представления в контроллере после отправки формы

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Проблема в обработке представления в контроллере после отправки формы. Объект сохраняет конвертируемое значение но не сохраняет конвертируемую валюту. Вопрос в следующем, проблема в коде формы представления, или в том что необходимо каким то образом обрабатывать полученные значения валюты в контролере. Ниже представлена отображаемая страница.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
  <title>Конвертер валют</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1> Конертер валюты </h1>
  <form method="POST" th:object="${ConvertedValue}">
    <li> <label> <select>
        <div th:each="currency : ${currencies}">
            <option th:value = "${currency.value}" th:text="${currency.charCode}"></option>
        </div>
    </select> <input type = "text" th:field="*{valueToConvert}"></label></li>>
    <li> <label> <select>
        <div th:each="currency : ${currencies}">
            <option th:text="${currency.charCode}"></option>
        </div>
    </select> <input type = "text" th:field="${ConvertedValue.convertResult}"></label></li>>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Конвертировать"></p>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Код класса контроллера

```html
@Slf4j
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/convert")
public class CurrencyConverterController {
    @GetMapping
    public String showCurrency(Model model) {
        List<Currency> currencies = new ArrayList<>();
        currencies.add(new Currency("R01235",840,"USD",1,"DollarUSA",73.2392));
        currencies.add(new Currency("R01239",978,"EUR",1,"EuropeanEURO", 87.4037));
        currencies.add(new Currency("R01270",356,"INR",100,"IndianRUPI", 97.8754));
        currencies.add(new Currency("R01230",282,"RU",1,"RussianMONEY",1));
            model.addAttribute("currencies",currencies);
            model.addAttribute("ConvertedValue", new ConvertedValue(0.0,0.0,currencies));
        return "convert";
    }

    @PostMapping
    public String convertMoney(@ModelAttribute ConvertedValue convertedValue) {
         //   System.out.println(convertedValue.getCurrenciesExc());
            System.out.println(convertedValue.toString());
        log.info("Converted value",convertedValue);
        return "redirect:/convert";
    }
}
```

Comment: Проблема решилась путём добавления данного кода в тег <select>. <select class = "CurrencyConverter" id = "0" name = "currencies">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не знаю, как это реализовано в thymeleaf, но нужно в select у нужной валюты выставить атрибут selected.